# How to listen parent click JS?

Tags: typescript, event-handling

I have HTML structure:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child_1"><div class="child_1_1"></div></div>
   <div class="child_2"></div>
</div>
```

So, when I click over parent element I call function:

```
 public openAccordion(event: any): void {
    if (event.target.className == "parent") {
       // TODO
    }
  }
```

To function I pass `event` and check if it contains specific class: `className`.

But when I click by child elements, this condition does not work, so, how always get parent container and check its class?

I assign like this:

```
<div(click)="openAccordion($event)">
```

Comment: Can you share more code to give context? How do you assign your event handlers?

Comment: Your code doesn't have an element with `sidebar__header` as class name

Comment: Updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens here is that your click event will bubble up to the parent where you handle the event. In the DOM event object, you have [different event targets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Comparison_of_Event_Targets) for different uses.

Instead of using `event.target` you can try to use `event.currentTarget` to get the element that the event handler is attached to.

The Angular `$event` should carry the contents of the original DOM event.